# gpm 1.20.7: I can't paste text

Tags: mouse, laptop, slackware, gpm

Slacware64-current (july 2020)
Kernel 5.4.50

Hi: This is from gpm's man page:
[code]
OPERATION
To select text press the left mouse button and drag the mouse.  To paste text in the same or another console, press the mid‐
dle button.  The right button is used to extend the selection, like in `xterm'.

```
   Two-button mice use the right button to paste text.
```

[/code]
I have a two-button mouse (actually a touchpad, this is a laptop). I am in a text console, say /dev/tty6, and I select an area with the left button. Now I press the right button... and nothing happens. Possible cause?

Comment: What laptop is it?

Comment: Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14 (AO1-431-C8G8).